# Errors attempting to add a web reference

Tags: sharepoint, wsdl, asmx

I have a link http://xxx.yyy.net/zzz/OpacAccess?wsdl that opens in IE and shows the methods of web service correctly.

However, I have a console application where I'm trying to add a web reference but I'm not able to get it working.  I right-click the project and click "Add service reference..."  From here, I click "Advanced..." and from there I click "Add Web Reference...".  When I enter the URL here, it shows me the methods correctly, but I'm unable to add the reference (the button is greyed-out) and the following error is shown:

There was an error downloading 'http://xxx.yyy.net/zzz/OpacAccess?wsdl'.  Unable to connect to the remote server.  No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:80.

If I use the visual studio command-line with the following command, 
wsdl http://xxx.yyy.net/zzz/OpacAccess?wsdl
, I get "There was an error processing http://xxx.yyy.net/zzz/OpacAccess?wsdl", followed by the above errors.

Thanks very much in advance for any assistance you could provide.

Comment: Why do you want a web reference? Why not just not click the "Advanced" button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, when you can access something through the browser, but not through another program you believe should work like the browser, then the problem is that the other program is not, in fact, behaving like the browser does.

The most common reason for this is proxy settings. The browser will usually  have them set (perhaps automatically through Group Policy or the equivalent), and your other program will not.